# How to pass database connection instance between PHP files without redeclaring it

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database connection instance in PHP like:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "blabla", "blabla");
```

I need to pass this database connection to other PHP files, since I have an HTML form that first inserts data into a database and then it goes to a PHP page that retrieves data.

I know that I must not instantiate the database connection each time but I do not know how to do it, because I am not so familiar with OO PHP.

Comment: include that file using `include()`

Answer (score 4):

You can just name a file connection.php and store your line for connection to database.
Then you can include your file like this :

```
require_once('connection.php');
```

This will be the content of connection.php :

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "blabla", "blabla");
```

And then this way, your file will never load twice.

Comment: to do it in an OOP way, you will use the singleton pattern to just get one instance. You can use this class : https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you misunderstand what you've read.

In PHP how most systems (phpBB, WordPress, etc) do it is there is a base include file that is included at the start of each PHP page. In phpBB it is called "Common.php" if I remember correctly.

Common.php goes through and does a few things:

1. It reads the database configuration files and connects via the most acceptable database connection type (mysql_connect, or mysqli_connect, depending, or another connection if you aren't using MySQL).
2. It then unsets the database password variable (so that someone, on an off chance, couldn't figure it out via SQL Injection)
3. includes other files necessary for the system to function - certain user-made functions or class definitions.

This is done via one of 4 functions:

`include('common.php')` will include the contents of the file at the point it is written in the file. E.G.

```
<?php
  do_function();
  include('common.php');
  do_other_function();
?>
```

Will run do_function(), then run any script in the common.php file, which could theoretically hold the definition for do_other_function(), and then run do_other_function();

`include_once('common.php')` makes sure that a file is run through the process only once. This is good for things like class definitions as it ensures a class is not accidentally re-defined. E.G.

```
<?php
   include_once('database_class.php');
   //Code here code here
   ...
   //Oh crap, did I include that database class? I can't remember. I think so...maybe not
   include_once('database_class.php');
?>
```

Will only include the database class def one time. Where as the same example above with `include('database_class.php');` instead of `include_once` would throw an error akin to `the class 'database' is already defined`

Note, include and include_once will only throw warnings if a file does not exist, and if you have error reporting set to only show fatal errors, you won't notice when something isn't included except for perhaps a "constant/function/class 'something' not defined" and you'll scratch your head for perhaps a long time. So if you try to include the file 'cmmon.php' when you meant 'common.php', you may or may not see an error.

then there is the `require` and `require_once` functions, they do effectively the same thing as `include` and `include_once`, but unlike the latter two the script will **stop running if it cannot include the file** and throw an error, like "could not include file 'something.php' on line # [line] in file [file path]"

Use require for scripts that are *absolutely* necessary - function/class/constants that your scripts will need in order run properly.

Use include for things that are voluntary, the first thought that came to mind would be plugins - things that don't necessarily have to be there in order for your system to work as intended.

Comment: It depends on your level of dedication / what you need from the class. The MySQLi object is actually best implemented (and was originally designed to be) OO. It can be used as such `$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','host','pw','db')` I can't fully explain it, but I can point you to the [PHP Website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) which should offer some insight. Otherwise, planning is always best. Decide what you need the object to do, what the base does on its own, and what you would need to add-in.

Answer (score 0):

If `$mysqli` is global, then all php files can see it by peeking the `$GLOBALS` array, assuming the php is included.

For example:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(..);   // in global space
```

another php file:

```
$GLOBALS["mysqli"];  // use that
```

inside a php function you could also do:

```
global $mysqli;    // use that
```

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, thanx for the link but it's mostly for C/dekstop environments. I can't find a reason why globals in PHP are bad. In this context sessions are even more bad.

Comment: They're both bad in this case, especially when all that is needed is an `include()` or `require()` in pages needing the connection.

Comment: aha, i see. Just include when you need them. tx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i think that the scope of using a global variable is only visible within one php file, i can not find a way to transfer the global variable to another php file. Let me know.

Comment: @pancy1, the scope of a global variable is visible to all php files that can included until the script exit. Consider a variable initialized outside a function in the starting file index.php, then this file includes 2 more files (b.php and c.php) and one of these files includes 1 more (d.php). In the file d.php the variable set in index.php would be visible, either directly (`$mysqli`) if used outside or via `$GLOBALS` array or by using the keyword **global** when using it inside a function. Check more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).